# Problem with amplifier?

Tags: amplifier

[image]

Hi. when I make experiment with BJT amplifier. I see the wave of output voltage is clipped at 2 peak. Can you explain me why ? And Does this problem happen with JFET amplifier, when ?

Comment: Please show the amplfier circuit, with input signal voltage and power supply voltages.  Very few of us are mind-readers.  This site has a schematic editor accessed by pressing control-M when editing your question.

Comment: Looks like it's clipping to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the bjt is in saturation at the high clips and in cutoff state at the low clips. You get this when the voltage levels (peak to peak) of your input signal is more than what your transistor can amplify. Lower the input signal until you see no clipping. Once the clipping is gone and you see that it does not amplify, you can try checking your circuit again, mainly the resistor values.

[Visit this for a refresher](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159014/why-are-bjt-operating-modes-named-the-way-they-are/159027#159027). You may want to read my answer on this regarding the states of BJT's. :D